# Loading assembly at runtime fails when I copy the DLL after program startup

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

At runtime I load an assembly with

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\MyFolder\MyAssembly.dll");
```

This works if the assembly is in that folder.

If the assembly is NOT in the folder I get an exception of course telling me that the assembly or one of its dependencies could not be found.

I'm catching the exception and display an error message to the user. The program keeps running.

If I copy now the missing assembly to the folder "c:\MyFolder" while the program is still running and trigger the function again which executes the line above **I get the same exception - a System.IO.FileNotFoundException - again that the assembly could not be found although the DLL is now in the folder**.

If I restart the application it works and the assembly is found. It also works if I start the application and copy the DLL to the folder before I try to load the assembly for the first time after application start.

So the problem seems to be related to the first failed call of `Assembly.LoadFrom`.

What can be the reason for this behaviour and what can I do to solve the problem?

Thank you for help in advance!

**Edit: One more detail:**

I've added a `File.Exists` test:

```
string filename = @"c:\MyFolder\MyAssembly.dll";
bool test = File.Exists(filename);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);
```

`test` returns `true` but `Assembly.LoadFrom` throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Feature, not a bug.  It is a DLL Hell counter-measure.  The operative term is 'loading context', search [Suzanne Cook's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/) for the phrase to learn more about it.  In a nutshell, the CLR memorizes previous attempts to load an assembly.  First and foremost, it records successful bindings and guarantees that the *exact* same assembly will be loaded again, even if the disk contents have changed.  You can no doubt see the benefit of that, suddenly getting *another* assembly is almost always disastrous.

The same is true for *failed* assembly binds.  It memorizes those as well, for much the same reason, it will fail them in the future.  There is no documented way to reset the loading context that I know of.  Assembly.LoadFile() loads assemblies without a loading context.  But that causes a whole range of other problems, you really don't want to use it.

Comment: Yes, I was strongly expecting that this wasn't a bug but some intended CLR feature I didn't know of. Question: When I have that failed assembly loading in another than my main `AppDomain` and I unload the other `AppDomain` after the exception, will a new try to load the copied assembly work?

Comment: Yes, I think loading contexts are associated with an AppDomain, not 100% sure.  The AppDomainSetup.LoaderOptimization and ShadowCopyFiles properties make it a bit tricky to give a definite answer.

Comment: Indeed, it works when I unload the AppDomain, create a new one and retry to load the assembly into that new AppDomain. I just tested it.

Answer (score 5):

In order to bypass the CLR caching of `LoadFrom` attempts, you can change your code a little to use the `Assembly.Load(byte[] rawAssembly)` overload.

Something like this:

```
Assembly LoadWithoutCache(string path)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var rawAssembly = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(rawAssembly, 0, rawAssembly.Length);
        return Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this also loads the assembly without a context according to the documentation, so it should be equivalent to Assembly.LoadFile().