# Copy referenced DLL to local directory on form load

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I have a program that was a .exe, and converted it to a DLL for a multitude of reasons. This DLL will need to be referenced by 3 separate programs, used throughout the company on various machines. The programs that will reference this DLL are copied locally before running.

We have another program with a similar setup, although it is only one program that uses one (separate) DLL. This program has the DLL added as a reference, with CopyLocal set to True. In the form load, the program looks to see if a new copy of the DLL is on the Q: drive and copies it locally if it is. This is the code it uses to copy the DLL

```
Private Sub frmFullCasePicking_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim LocalInfo As IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\tmp\vbPrintLabelDLL.dll")
        Dim RemoteInfo As IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("Q:\vbPrintLabelDLL.dll")
        If LocalInfo.LastWriteTime < RemoteInfo.LastWriteTime Then My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("Q:\vbPrintLabelDLL.dll", "C:\tmp\vbPrintLabelDLL.dll", True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("Q:\vbPrintLabelDLL.dll") Then My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("Q:\vbPrintLabelDLL.dll", "C:\tmp\vbPrintLabelDLL.dll")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I am attempting to do the same thing with the new DLL, but I am getting an exception that the DLL is already in use by another process. Is there a setting or something that I am missing? It doesn't appear to me that the program where this works does anything special with loading the DLL during runtime or anything of that nature, it just copies the newest version (and uses the new version throughout the rest of the program's run).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: The only difference I can find between the program where this process works and my "new" one where it doesn't is the .NET framework version the projects were built for. The setup where it works was built for .NET framework 2.0, whereas the newer one is 3.5

EDIT: Here is the exact error message from the `Catch` block. Also, please note that the program also resides in 'C:\tmp\' on each machine.

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\rbattle\Desktop\Documents\dotNet Source Code\vbFullCasePicking - Using DLL\vbFullCasePicking\bin\Release\vbPrintLabelDLL.dll' because it is being used by another process.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     
    at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)     
    at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyOrMoveFile(CopyOrMove operation, String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, Boolean overwrite, UIOptionInternal showUI, UICancelOption onUserCancel)     
    at Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.FileSystemProxy.CopyFile(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, Boolean overwrite)     
    at vbFullCasePicking.frmFullCasePicking.frmFullCasePicking_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\rbattle\Desktop\Documents\dotNet Source Code\vbFullCasePicking - Using DLL\vbFullCasePicking\frmFullCasePicking.vb:line 103
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I hadn't seen this anywhere in all the research I did (although I'm not sure I was searching for the right thing), but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622802/lazy-load-a-dll-that-was-placed-on-the-filesystem-after-the-program-has-been-sta?rq=1) gave me the solution.

He mentioned that DLLs aren't referenced until needed. I have a class level member on the form which also contains the form load function above, and as the form members are processed before the form load function begins, the DLL gets loaded before the code above runs. I temporarily removed the class level variable, and it copied the DLL perfectly fine.

To remedy this, I moved the code to check and copy the DLL into the Startup event under ApplicationEvents, so it copies before the form is loaded and thus my class level variable can still be used in the same manner as I had it.

Comment: Hmya, this won't be the last mishap.  Other plain failure modes are the user starting the program twice and anti-malware giving it the "where the heck did *this* come from" treatment.  You must assume this isn't going to work.

Comment: I've actually tested this already and haven't run into any issues (at least with multiple instances running at the same time, and being started at the same time). The anti-malware bit isn't so easy to test, I would imagine. I've added code so that if the DLL isn't where it's supposed to be, the program throws an error and exits, and also if the DLL is there but there is a newer version that couldn't be copied.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you change `Catch ex As Exception` so that it catches a specific type of exception, instead of ALL exceptions.

The code in the try block may be throwing any number of exceptions which would point you right to the problem (security, connectivity, etc).

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post...I'm displaying the `ex.ToString` in a message box, I've updated the code to reflect this and added the exact error message.